# How do you use connect-livereload in grunt?

Tags: gruntjs, livereload, grunt-contrib-connect

I was struggling to get my server to reload so I followed some links and ended up at [`connect-livereload`](https://github.com/intesso/connect-livereload).

However, when I try to use the grunt code in my grunt file

```
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 3000,
    hostname: 'localhost'
  },
  dev: {
    options: {
      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          require('connect-livereload')(), // <--- here
          checkForDownload,
          mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
          mountFolder(connect, 'app')
        ];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get this error in my grunt console:

```
Warning: checkForDownload is not defined Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

The documentation for `connect-livereload` is so horrendous, there is no mention of what `checkForDownload`, or `mountFolder` is supposed to me.

Does anyone know?